# Why is UNION faster than an OR statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have a problem where I need to find records that either have a measurement that matches a value, **or** do not have that measurement at all. I solved that problem with three or four different approaches, using `JOIN`s, using `NOT IN` and using `NOT EXISTS`. However, the query ended up being extremely slow every time. I then tried splitting the query in two, and they both run very fast (three seconds). But combining the queries using `OR` takes more than five minutes.

Reading on SO I tried `UNION`, which is very fast, but very inconvenient for the script I am using.

So two questions:

1. Why is `UNION` so much faster? (Or why is `OR` so slow)?
2. Is there any way I can force SQL Server to use a different approach for the `OR` statement that is fast?

Comment: can you show us the sql you are referring to.

Comment: Perhaps show us the statements you tried in full?

Comment: I was hoping we could do without because I would need to rename all the fields and tables. Is this really specific for my query? From what I found on Google this is quite a common problem.

Comment: you dont need to rename all of the columns, but if you have a specific question you need to create a SQL fiddle.  It is of no benefit to the community or yourself without this information.  We know nothing about your schema (indexes and such)

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as a duplicate because UNION ALL and UNION have different behaviours

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason is that using `OR` in a query will often cause the Query Optimizer to abandon use of index seeks and revert to scans. If you look at the execution plans for your two queries, you'll most likely see scans where you are using the `OR` and seeks where you are using the `UNION`. Without seeing your query it's not really possible to give you any ideas on how you might be able to restructure the `OR` condition. But you may find that inserting the rows into a temporary table and joining on to it may yield a positive result.

Also, it is generally best to use `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION` if you want all results, as you remove the cost of row-matching.

Comment: And I can't trick it into using index scans using OR?

Comment: @saratis - You may well be able to, but without seeing your SQL I can't give you a firm answer, really.

Comment: Thanks a million, Matt for your explanation. Also thanks Matt for your question. Had a similar problem with a query on an ORACLE server, and this helps me a lot.

Answer (score 6):

There is currently no way in SQL Server to force a `UNION` execution plan if no `UNION` statement was used. If the only difference between the two parts is the `WHERE` clause, create a view with the complex query. The `UNION` query then becomes very simple:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyView WHERE <cond1>
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyView WHERE <cond2>
```

It is important to use `UNION ALL` in this context when ever possible. If you just use `UNION` SQL Server has to filter out duplicate rows, which requires an expensive sort operation in most cases.

Comment: *"It is important to use UNION ALL in this context when ever possible. If you just use UNION SQL Server has to filter out duplicate rows, which requires an expensive sort operation in most cases."* True, but this changes the behavior, because `OR` did not return duplicate rows. Thus, I'd change the answer to use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` (since this will be a correctness-preserving transformation) and mention `UNION ALL` as an additional possibility for performance optimization **if** `<cond1>` and `<cond2>` are guaranteed to be distinct (or the calling code can handle duplicates).