# Where one or another column exists in a sub select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, where-clause

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d FROM someTable WHERE
    WHERE a in (SELECT testA FROM otherTable);
```

Only I want to be able to test if 2 columns exist in a sub select of 2 columns.

```
SELECT a, b, c, d FROM someTable WHERE
    WHERE a OR b in (SELECT testA, testB FROM otherTable);
```

We are using MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: Can you give some sample data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT a, b, c, d 
FROM someTable WHERE
WHERE a IN (SELECT testA FROM otherTable) 
   OR b IN (SELECT testB FROM otherTable)
```

or

```
 SELECT a, b, c, d 
        FROM someTable WHERE
        WHERE EXISTS 
          (SELECT NULL 
           FROM otherTable 
           WHERE testA = a OR testB = a 
             OR testA = b OR testB = b)
```

**UPDATE:** 
Maybe you need to add index on testB column, if you have bad performance.
Also another option to use `CROSS APPLY` for `MS SQL`

```
SELECT a, b, c, d 
        FROM someTable ST
           CROSS APPLY (
               SELECT 1
               FROM otherTable OT
               WHERE OT.testA = ST.a OR OT.testB = ST.b
           )
```

If any of this won't work, try using **UNION**. Mostly **UNION** gives better performance than **OR**

```
SELECT a, b, c, d 
    FROM someTable WHERE
    WHERE a IN (SELECT testA FROM otherTable)
 UNION
    SELECT a, b, c, d 
    FROM someTable WHERE
    WHERE b IN (SELECT testB FROM otherTable)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

For further reading on OR and UNION differences

[Why is UNION faster than an OR statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361972/why-is-union-faster-than-an-or-statement)

Comment: I had actually tried your first option but it was giving us incredibly bad performance. Just tried the WHERE EXISTS and same thing, very very slow. If I only compare one value, like testA = a its super fast. As soon as I add the OR testB = b it takes 34 seconds.

Comment: Interestingly the union is much much faster. Though our actual use is much more complicated than my simple example. Our main query is 72 lines and we are actually comparing 6 values not just 2. So union makes us having to do those 72 lines 6 times. I'm not an SQL expert but that seems dirty and inefficient.

Comment: @Rookie Agree, union looks much more complicated, but we had the same issue and solved it by changing or to union. You can read about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361972/why-is-union-faster-than-an-or-statement

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, `LEFT JOIN` is probably the way to go here:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d
FROM TableA ta
LEFT JOIN TableB tb
ON ta.a = tb.a
    AND ta.b = tb.b
WHERE tb.a IS NOT NULL
    AND tb.c IS NOT NULL
```

You could also use UNION and INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d
FROM someTable
INNER JOIN OtherTable OT on someTable.B = OT.testB
UNION
SELECT a, b, c, d
FROM someTable
INNER JOIN OtherTable OT ON someTable.A= OT.testA
```

Note that the JOIN approach should be orders of magnitude faster if you have an index on the column

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
SELECT a, b, c, d 
FROM someTable 
WHERE Exists 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM otherTable 
    Where a = testA OR b = testB 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Joins seems to be one option, have you thought about using them with a Union?

```
SELECT a, b, c, d 
FROM someTable 
INNER JOIN OtherTable OT on someTable.B = OT.testB 
UNION 
SELECT a, b, c, d 
FROM someTable 
INNER JOIN OtherTable OT ON someTable.A= OT.testA
```